# Copy a file with its parent directory structure in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a little patcher in PowerShell which first backs up the files before replacing them. But I can't get it to cooperate when the file is in a subdirectory. To simplify:

First, it creates the backup directory:
`$Null = New-Item -Path 'C:\Backup' -ItemType 'Directory'`

Next, I check for the file:
`[System.IO.FileInfo]$FileInfo = Get-Item -LiteralPath 'C:\App\bin\executable.exe'`

Now, I want this file to end up in `C:\Backup\bin\executable.exe`

The first thing I tried was to get the `FullName` and replace `C:\App` with `C:\Backup` resulting in `$FileInfo | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Backup\bin\executable.exe'`

But it keeps throwing an exception because `C:\Backup\bin` does not exist. I tried combinations of the `-Recurse` and `-Container` switches.

I assume the issue is that I'm setting the full path as my destination, resulting in no relative paths being created. But I don't see another way to get that target path set. I can't tell it to copy to `C:\Backup\bin` because there's no logical way for me to know about `bin` without extracting it. At which point I might as well create it in the backup directory.

But I kind of want this to be automagic (for the `C:\App\multi\level\path\file.dll` at a later stage). This makes the script more flexible if I change the file locations later on.

I'm probably missing something really obvious here. Any suggestions?

---

This is what I'm doing now, compensating for having to make the parent directories myself. I'm open to ways to optimize and of course still looking for a way to not have to explicitly create the parent directories.

```
Function Backup-Item {
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] [System.String]$Source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] [System.String]$SourceRoot,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)][System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]$Backup = $True,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)][System.String]$BackupDirectory
  ) # Param

  Begin {
    If (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Source) { [System.IO.FileInfo]$SourceFile = Get-Item -LiteralPath $Source }
    Else { } # TODO: Break

    If ($Backup) {
      If (Test-Path -LiteralPath $BackupDirectory) { } # TODO: Break
      Else { $Null = New-Item -Path $BackupDirectory -ItemType 'Directory' }

      [System.String]$Destination = $SourceFile.FullName.Replace($SourceRoot,$BackupDirectory)
    } # If
  } # Begin

  Process {
    If ($Backup) {
      [System.String]$TargetDirectory = $SourceFile.DirectoryName.Replace($SourceRoot,$BackupDirectory)
      If (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $TargetDirectory)) { $Null = New-Item -Path $TargetDirectory -ItemType 'Directory' }

      $SourceFile | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
    } # If
  } # Process

  End {}
} # Function Backup-Item
```

I don't like having to provide the `SourceRoot` but it's the only way to deduce the relative paths I could think of.

I will also need to make `BackupDirectory` mandatory but only if `Backup` is True (which is the default and a bit dirty since a switch should be off by default, but I wanted the ability to do `-Backup:$False` to override).

I would use this as a helper script in the larger patcher-script.

Comment: You don't need to provide the name again when copying a file. It's also redundant to cast a type of `fileinfo` to an object that's being returned as such. Have you tried the `-Force` switch? It will create the directory for you.

Comment: I started with the ```FullName``` cast as a ```String``` first. I turned it into a ```FileInfo``` object later so I could use the versatility in the pipeline. That the filename is in the ```Destination``` parameter is the result of me using a string replacement in the absolute path of the source file (replacing ```App``` with ```Backup```) Oh and I always cast everything explicitly, remnant of my coding days. I will try the ```Force``` switch (I think I already did the first time though).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use robocopy to copy the entire `C:\Apps` folder to the `C:\Backup` folder, like with

```
robocopy C:\Apps C:\Backup /MIR
```

If you want pure PowerShell, you can do

```
$sourcePath = 'C:\Apps'
$backupPath = 'C:\Backup'
Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # create the destination folder, even if it is empty
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $backupPath -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($sourcePath.Length)
    $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $targetFolder -Force
    # next copy the file
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFolder
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a PoSh native solution. RIght now I'm extracting the full path, replacing ```C:\App``` with ```C:\Backup``` and then creating those directories first. But it seems so strange that there's switch or similar which can do it for you (copy and create parents if those don't exist).